# Jackson XML marshal error when XmlAttribute and XmlElement have the same name

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb

Jackson XML appears not to be able to marshal a XML having a tag with a certain attribute whose name is also being used for the nested children tags ("occ", in the following case).

```
<root>
    <txt occ="1">
        <occ id="1">first element</occ>
        <occ id="2">second element</occ>
    </txt>
    <txt occ="2">
        <occ id="1">first element</occ>
        <occ id="2">second element</occ>
    </txt>
</root>
```

Changing the name of the XmlAttribute "occ" or of the XmlElement "occ" makes it work.

This is how I've annotated my Txt Class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Txt {

@XmlAttribute(name="occ")
private String occ_attr;

@XmlElement(name="occ")
private List<Occ> occ = new ArrayList<Occ>();

//getters and setters not annotated
```

And this is how I've annotated the Occ class:

```
public class Occ {

@XmlAttribute
private String id;

@XmlValue
private String value;

//getters and setters not annotated
```

Comment: Where is the question ? I didn't understand what is the issue ?

Comment: The question is how to make the marshal work given that the attribute has the same name of the children elements.

Comment: Your current code worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's an issue of the library. As of today, the issue hasn't been solved yet:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/65

Answer (score 0):

I wrap them within a root and it worked.

Test class

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String...args) throws JAXBException {
        String text = "<root>\n" + 
                "    <txt occ=\"1\">\n" + 
                "        <occ id=\"1\">first element</occ>\n" + 
                "        <occ id=\"2\">second element</occ>\n" + 
                "    </txt>\n" + 
                "    <txt occ=\"2\">\n" + 
                "        <occ id=\"1\">first element</occ>\n" + 
                "        <occ id=\"2\">second element</occ>\n" + 
                "    </txt>\n" + 
                "</root>";


        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(text);
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        System.out.println(root);


        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(root, sw);
        String xmlContent = sw.toString();
        System.out.println(xmlContent);

    }


}
```

Txt class

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Txt {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "occ")
    private String occ_attr;

    @XmlElement(name = "occ")
    private ArrayList<Occ> occ;

    public String getOcc_attr() {
        return occ_attr;
    }

    public void setOcc_attr(String occ_attr) {
        this.occ_attr = occ_attr;
    }

    public List<Occ> getOcc() {
        return occ;
    }

    public void setOcc(ArrayList<Occ> occ) {
        this.occ = occ;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Txt [occ_attr=" + occ_attr + ", occ=" + occ + "]";
    }

}
```

Occ class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Occ {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Occ [id=" + id + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }

}
```

Root class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {
    @XmlElement(name = "txt")
    private ArrayList<Txt> txt;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Root [txt=" + txt + "]";
    }

}
```

prints out:

```
Root [txt=[Txt [occ_attr=1, occ=[Occ [id=1, value=first element], Occ [id=2, value=second element]]], Txt [occ_attr=2, occ=[Occ [id=1, value=first element], Occ [id=2, value=second element]]]]]

<root>
    <txt occ="1">
        <occ id="1">first element</occ>
        <occ id="2">second element</occ>
    </txt>
    <txt occ="2">
        <occ id="1">first element</occ>
        <occ id="2">second element</occ>
    </txt>
</root>
```

Comment: It does not work properly, just as I've indicated in the question. 
Check and you will see that the ArrayList<Occ> occ is not being populated.
If you serialize the object again you will see that the XML is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <txt/>
   <txt/>
</root>

Comment: Yes it works properly. I updated my answer. It marshalls and unmarshalls properly.

Comment: What JDK are you using?

Comment: Version 1.8.0_191